# how to link entity, session and manage bean in JSF application

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, managed-bean

I am new to Java EE and developing first Java EE login application using netbeans 7.1.2. I have db table & entity named 'Users' with few naded queries, a session bean 'UsersFacade' containing persistance unit, and method named 'authenticaate' below is code

```
public Users authenticate(String login_id, String pwd) {       
    Users user = (Users) em.createNamedQuery("Users.authenticate")
            .setParameter("login_name", login_id) 
            .setParameter("password", pwd)
            .getResultList().get(0);
```

finally i have jsf managed bean which is sessionscoped containing two local members login_name and password, jsf page login.xhtml is bound with these fields, this bean also has authenticate method which in turn calls session bean 'UserFacade' authenticate message

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Login implements Serializable {
        private String login_name;
        private String password;

        private Users user;
        private @EJB UsersFacade user_services;

        public String authenticate() {
            user = user_services.authenticate(this.getLogin_name(),this.getPassword());
            if (user != null){            
                return "home";
            } else {
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage("login", new FacesMessage("Invalid UserName and Password"));
                return "login";
            }
```

every thing works fine till this point.  However, on home page i want to display all data members of users table so that i can modify values and save record. in home page i coded like:

```
                <h:outputText value="Welcome #{login.user.login_name}" />
```

assuming i have declared user (entity) in managed bean and i should be able to access property of entity but when i run application, i get following error:

The class 'controller.Login' does not have the property 'user'

can any one suggest what i am doing wrong and what is ideal way of binding jsf page with managed bean if i have 3 different implementations for 1 managed bean (3 different user interface for 3 different role/types of users). I am using JPA (entity,session) & JSF managed bean. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> *The class 'controller.Login' does not have the property 'user'*

You will get this error when there is no getter method for the mentioned property in the mentioned class. Make sure that you have supplied a valid getter method.

```
public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}
```